# Quickly code conditional if-then statements in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

Does anyone have any idea if there is a faster way to code this? I'm working on an excel sheet where if you click a check box, True appears in the cell. Then  if the cell if true then....However there are 11 possible selections meaning there are literally millions of possible combinations and the writing each line of code and double checking it is killing me. Example below of code (only 10 of the possible combinations.

```
   If Worksheets("Overview").Range("B36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("C36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("D36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("E36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("F36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("G36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("H36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("I36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("J36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("K36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("L36").Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please select engagement components."

    ElseIf Worksheets("Overview").Range("B36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("C36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("D36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("E36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("F36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("G36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("H36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("I36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("J36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("K36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("L36").Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Cost: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C33").Value & vbNewLine & "Hours: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C25").Value & vbNewLine & "Scope: "

ElseIf Worksheets("Overview").Range("B36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("C36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("D36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("E36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("F36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("G36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("H36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("I36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("J36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("K36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("L36").Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Cost: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("D33").Value & vbNewLine & "Hours: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("D25").Value & vbNewLine & "Scope: "

    ElseIf Worksheets("Overview").Range("B36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("C36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("D36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("E36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("F36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("G36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("H36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("I36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("J36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("K36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("L36").Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Cost: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("D33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("E33").Value & vbNewLine & "Hours: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("D25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("E25").Value & vbNewLine & "Scope: "

     ElseIf Worksheets("Overview").Range("B36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("C36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("D36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("E36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("F36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("G36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("H36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("I36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("J36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("K36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("L36").Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Cost: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("D33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("E33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("F33") & vbNewLine & "Hours: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("D25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("E25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("F25").Value & vbNewLine & "Scope: "

    ElseIf Worksheets("Overview").Range("B36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("C36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("D36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("E36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("F36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("G36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("H36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("I36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("J36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("K36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("L36").Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Cost: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("D33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("E33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("F33") + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("G33") & vbNewLine & "Hours: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("D25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("E25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("F25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("G25") & vbNewLine & "Scope: "

    ElseIf Worksheets("Overview").Range("B36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("C36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("D36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("E36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("F36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("G36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("H36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("I36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("J36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("K36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("L36").Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Cost: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("D33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("E33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("F33") + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("G33") + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("H33") & vbNewLine & "Hours: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("D25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("E25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("F25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("G25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("H25") & vbNewLine & "Scope: "

    ElseIf Worksheets("Overview").Range("B36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("C36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("D36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("E36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("F36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("G36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("H36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("I36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("J36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("K36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("L36").Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Cost: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("D33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("E33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("F33") + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("G33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("H33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("I33").Value & vbNewLine & "Hours: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("D25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("E25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("F25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("G25") + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("H25") + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("I25").Value & vbNewLine & "Scope: "

    ElseIf Worksheets("Overview").Range("B36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("C36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("D36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("E36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("F36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("G36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("H36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("I36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("J36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("K36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("L36").Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Cost: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("D33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("E33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("F33") + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("G33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("H33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("I33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("J33").Value & vbNewLine & "Hours: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("D25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("E25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("F25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("G25") + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("H25") + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("I25").Value & vbNewLine & "Scope: "

    ElseIf Worksheets("Overview").Range("B36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("C36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("D36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("E36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("F36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("G36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("H36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("I36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("J36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("K36").Value = "" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("L36").Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Cost: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("D33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("E33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("F33") + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("G33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("H33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("I33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("J33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("K33").Value & vbNewLine & "Hours: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("D25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("E25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("F25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("G25") + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("H25") + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("I25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("J25").Value & vbNewLine & "Scope: "

    ElseIf Worksheets("Overview").Range("B36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("C36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("D36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("E36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("F36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("G36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("H36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("I36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("J36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("K36").Value = "True" And Worksheets("Overview").Range("L36").Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Cost: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("D33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("E33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("F33") + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("G33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("H33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("I33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("J33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("K33").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("L33").Value & vbNewLine & "Hours: " & Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("C25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("D25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("E25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("F25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("G25") + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("H25") + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("I25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("J25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("K25").Value + Worksheets("Billing Rates").Range("L25").Value
```

Comment: If this is working code, might I suggest Code Review Stack Exchange?

Comment: Also you could use nested Ifs since you seem to have the same condition in many of the lines of code (that would shorten code significantly)

Answer (score 3):

The awnser is doing ifs inside other ifs, or sequential ifs, storing the values, and presenting a message in the final line:

```
Dim msg as String
If A = True Then
    If B = True Then
        msg = "A and B is True"
    Else
        msg = "A is True B is False"
    End If
End If
MsgBox msg
```

Or

```
If A = True Then
    msg = "A is true"
Else
    msg = "A is false"
EndIf
If B = True Then
    msg = msg & " and B is True"
Else
    msg = msg & " and B is False"
End If
MsgBox msg
```

You don't need to check the same conditions over and over.

Answer (score 1):

The values retrieved for cost and hours from the Billing Rates seem to be offset one column from the cells being examined on the Overview worksheet, albeit on different rows.

```
Dim chk As Long, dBRC As Double, dBRH As Double
Dim wsBR As Worksheet

Set wsBR = Worksheets("Billing Rates")

With Worksheets("Overview")
    If Not CBool(Application.CountA(.Range("B36:L36"))) Then
        Debug.Print "Please select engagement components."
    Else
        For chk = 2 To 12
            'only collect the even numbered columns
            Select Case chk
                Case 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12
                    If .Cells(36, chk) = "True" Then   '<~~ is this supposed to be an actual boolean True or a string that looks like "True"?
                        dBRC = dBRC + wsBR.Cells(33, chk + 1).Value2
                        dBRH = dBRH + wsBR.Cells(25, chk + 1).Value2
                    End If
                Case Else
                    'do nothing
            End Select
        Next chk
    End If
End With

Debug.Print "Cost: " & Format(dBRC, "$0.00") & vbNewLine & "Hours: " & dBRH & vbNewLine & "Scope: "
```

I could not reconcile what you planned to do with the **Scope:** label.

Comment: Your code works amazing! Is there a way to get it to pull without the plus one feature though? So for example if I wanted to select only a few combinations.

Comment: Use an array of the columns to chk or a select case to include/discard individual columns.

Comment: Ooops! I didn't see your response! How do you do a select case to include/discard?

Comment: see above for even numbered columns

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do this something like this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, wsB As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Overview")
Set wsB = Worksheets("BillingRates")

Dim trueCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Cst, Hrs

For i = 1 To 11

    If ws.Range(Chr(65 + i) & "36").Value = "True" Then
        trueCount = trueCount + 1
        Cst = Cst + wsB.Range(Chr(66 + i) & "33").Value
        Hrs = Hrs + wsB.Range(Chr(66 + i) & "25").Value
    End If

    If trueCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please select engagement components."
    Else
        MsgBox "Cost: " & Cst _
        & vbNewLine & "Hours: " & Hrs _
        & vbNewLine & "Scope: "
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: Hi RBarryYoung! Your code works really well but I keep getting the message boxes pop-uping in the middle of some of the calculations, do you know how to stop those from appearing?

Comment: @CodingNewb They are only created if you are calling this code.  MsgBox can be pretty intrusive, so you could change them to Debug.Print as Jeeped did.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to RBarryYoung and Jeeped for helping me with this problem, I would be really up a creek without your help. I figured out how to get the pop-ups from reoccurring. Below is the final code I ended up using:

Sub Way_EatFresh()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, wsB As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Overview")
Set wsB = Worksheets("Billing Rates")

Dim trueCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Cst, Hrs

For i = 1 To 11

If ws.Range(Chr(65 + i) & "36").Value = "True" Then
    trueCount = trueCount + 1
    Cst = Cst + wsB.Range(Chr(66 + i) & "33").Value
    Hrs = Hrs + wsB.Range(Chr(66 + i) & "25").Value
End If

Next i

If trueCount > 0 Then
   MsgBox "Cost: " & Cst _
    & vbNewLine & "Hours: " & Hrs _
    & vbNewLine & ""
End If

If trueCount = 0 Then
     MsgBox "Please select engagement components."
End If
End Sub
```